# Save a change to published app will update the version or not?

Tags: android, publish

I have published an app on play.google.com and then i made a change to it and added the new apk and saved without unpublishing and publishing it again. Will it update the app version or not?

Comment: The app will be updated but the version number will be whatever you have declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that'll get sent out to the users as long as you've activated the new APK (click the APK files tab and check the latest version is the active version).